# Making `CReal` and `BigFloat e` in Data.Number instances of `Unbox`

Tags: haskell

If I want to use `CReal` or `BigFloat e` in Data.Number (more accuracy than `Double`) in unboxed vectors, I have to give them instances of `Unbox`. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you're looking for a more accuracy than `Double` that can be unboxed, try [`compensated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compensated). It already contains the `Unbox` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sources of `CReal` and `BigFloat`, it seems that neither of them can be unboxed.

`CReal` can't be unboxed because it's [a function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/src/Data-Number-CReal.html#CReal):

```
data CReal = CR (Int -> Integer)
```

`BigFloat` [contains](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-BigFloat.html) `Integer`, and `Integer` can't be unboxed either, because it is backed by a variable-sized bytearray.

Comment: Basically, only types with finite information content can be unboxed. It's the very nature of `CReal` to have possibly-infinite information content, “infinite resolution”. For `BigFloat` this is not so clear – I suppose one could devise a similar type that _would_, for any given precision, be unboxable.